# "KeyError: 'outputs_list' " in using plotly dash for showing pie chart

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash

I am trying to show a pie chart on my web app using plotly dash but by using @app.callback its showing following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\PRESONAL DATA\FROSK CODING\untitled3.py", line 84, in <module>
 main()

File "D:\PRESONAL DATA\FROSK CODING\untitled3.py", line 72, in main
pie_chart()

File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1006, in add_context
output_spec = kwargs.pop("outputs_list")

KeyError: 'outputs_list'
```

I tried everything can't understand what to do
**Here is the code :-**

```
project_name = None
bs = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootswatch@4.5.2/dist/slate/bootstrap.min.css'
app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[bs], suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

# Defining My Functions
def load_model():
     global scrappedReviews
     scrappedReviews = pd.read_csv('balanced_reviews.csv')

     global pickle_model
     file = open("model_pickle.pkl", 'rb') 
     pickle_model = pickle.load(file)

     global vocab
     file = open("vocab_pickle.pkl", 'rb') 
     vocab = pickle.load(file)



def check_review(reviewText):


    transformer = TfidfTransformer()
    loaded_vec = CountVectorizer(decode_error="replace",vocabulary=vocab)
    vectorised_review = transformer.fit_transform(loaded_vec.fit_transform([reviewText]))

    return pickle_model.predict(vectorised_review)

def open_browser():
    webbrowser.open_new('http://127.0.0.1:8050/')

def create_app_ui():
    main_layout = html.Div(
        [
        html.H1(id='main_title', children='Chech Emotions'),

        html.Div(
            dcc.Graph(id='graph')
        ),

        dbc.Input(
            id='textarea_review',
            placeholder = 'Enter the review here....',
            type = "text",
            style = {'width':'50%', 'height':50}
        ),

        html.H1(id='result', children=None)
            ]         
            )

return main_layout


@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure')
)
def pie_chart():

    df = pd.read_csv('prediction.csv')
    piechart = go.pie(
            data_frame=dff,
            values='status',
            names='predictions'
           )

return piechart


@app.callback(
    Output('result',  'children' ),
    [
    Input('textarea_review', 'value' )
    ]
)
def update_app_ui(textarea_value):
    print('Data Type of ', str(type(textarea_value)))
    print('Value = ', str(textarea_value) )

    response = check_review (textarea_value)
    print('response = ', response)

    if (response[0] == 0):
        result1 = 'Negative'
    elif  (response[0] == 1):
        result1 = 'Positive'
    else:
        result1 = 'Unknown'
    
return result1

# Main Function to control the Flow of your Project
def main():
    print("Start of my project")

    load_model()
    open_browser()

    
    global project_name
    global scrappedReviews
    global app


    project_name = "Sentiment Analysis with Insights"

    app.title = project_name
    pie_chart()
    app.layout = create_app_ui()
    app.run_server()


    print("End of my project")
    project_name = None
    scrappedReviews = None
    app = None

# Calling the main function 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**prediction.csv** contains 2 column predictions = {0, 1}*4520 and status = {'Positive', 'Negative'}*4520
Any guidance will surely help please

Answer (score 0):

This callback is defined incorrectly:

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure')
)
def pie_chart():
```

You need to have Inputs as well. For example:

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('foo', 'bar')]
)
def pie_chart():
```

Comment: but if i define input in callback i have to take input from somewhere of my app.....but I am not taking any input just want to show pie of info on my csv........i didn't applied any bar or dropdown

Comment: If there's no input, then you don't need a callback. Just put that code directly in the layout.